# Running Multiple Applications which uses global/static data in RTOS

Tags: operating-system, rtos

Is there any small hard/soft RTOS (like Free RTOS) supporting running multiple applications (which can be re-launched again & again) which uses global/static data?

To be exact, is there any RTOS targeting small MCU's like Cortex-M*/R* which supports data address space like Linux process’s?
If not, what is best approach to handle these applications other than "loader + dynamic linking + shared libraries"?

Thank you,

Comment: what do you mean "which supports data address space like Linux process’s"? What is data address space?

Comment: I mean, data & bss section of an application.

Comment: you mean rtos which supports ELF loader?

Comment: yes. 
Also, Is there a way to support multiple applications without loader support at the OS level?. If applications uses global data, data/bss initializes only one time during bootup. So how to re-initialize each time the applications starts?

Comment: Almost any, you can consider Nuttx for example http://www.nuttx.org/

Comment: Thanks.. I am familiar with Nuttx and Its binary loader support. In order to use that, application will be built seperately with PIE and stored in File system. But can it be achieved without using Binary loader in flat binary?... Is there a way? ..

Comment: Does FreeRTOS support this?